# Specifying column classes in read.csv.sql

Tags: r, sqldf

When reading in a .csv using `read.csv.sql` from the `sqldf` package, is it possible to specify the column classes rather than having the function guess at them from the contents?

Supposing I have a .csv file too large to read using base `read.csv`, with a column I know to be character class but that almost always contains numeric values. Then no positive value of `nrows` will be guaranteed to catch the non-numeric values and thus assign the correct class, and `nrows=-1` will load the entire colum vecotr into R, avoiding doing which is the reason I'm using `read.csv.sql`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example from [sqldf](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#example-8-specifying-file-format) home page.

```
library(sqldf)

# example example 8a - file.format attribute on file.object

numStr <- as.character(1:100)
DF <- data.frame(a = c(numStr, "Hello"))
write.table(DF, file = "~/tmp.csv", quote = FALSE, sep = ",")
ff <- file("~/tmp.csv")

attr(ff, "file.format") <- list(colClasses = c(a = "character"))

tail(sqldf("select * from ff"))


# example 8b - using file.format argument

numStr <- as.character(1:100)
DF <- data.frame(a = c(numStr, "Hello"))
write.table(DF, file = "~/tmp.csv", quote = FALSE, sep = ",")
ff <- file("~/tmp.csv")

tail(sqldf("select * from ff",
 file.format = list(colClasses = c(a = "character"))))
```

Comment: But (and sorry if I'm being slow here) how can I use this in `read.csv.sql`? If I just include the `file.format` argument, I get an error ("formal argument "file.format" matched by multiple actual arguments")

Comment: I believe that there has been a bug introduced into a recent version of RSQLite that causes `colClasses` not to be accepted.  I have contacted the RSQLite maintainer about this.